# how i can check if there is a repetition of the same results in a table?

Tags: python, data-science, grouping

I have read a few similar questions on counting consecutive rows, but none of them gave me a clear answer. I hope someone could give me some help with my problem. I have the following table data:

`ID       TEST_VALUES
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       C
5       C
6       C
7       A
8       D
9       D
10      D
11      B
12      C
13      C
14      C
15      C`

now I want to find if there  three consecutive rows with the same value how i can do it ?

Comment: I suggest you post some code that shows how this table is represented in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have read a few similar questions on counting consecutive rows, but none of them gave me a clear answer. I hope someone could give me some help with my problem. I have the following table data:

```
ID       TEST_VALUES
 1       A
 2       B
 3       C
 4       C
 5       C
 6       C
 7       A
 8       D
 9       D
 10      D
 11      B
 12      C
 13      C
 14      C
 15      C
```

Now I want to find three consecutive rows with the same value.

How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).